# Automatically enable Named Pipes & TCP/IP protocols SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, automation, named-pipes, tcp, silent-installer

We have a C# win Form app called "Installer" that **silently** installs various 3rd party software on client's system like IIS, SQL Server, AVG-Free; along with our own product. I need to automatically enable Named Pipes & TCP/IP protocols which also require a restart of SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) Service using a batch file; OR C# win Form app; OR while installing SQL Server through command line by providing appropriate switches.
I have searched but this is very unique requirement.

Comment: Why do you need to silently install a browser? That seems kind of shady. I'd probably remove it from the question since it has no relevance, but I would seriously reconsider that aspect...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Our product requires Latest Version of IE, OR latest Firefox, the later seems to be a better option with easy silent install, and no updates/fixes/SPs.  Our clients are dumb, we cannot give them any instructions to install any software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution, tried it. The protocol info of SQL Server in registry is store here:

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.**MSSQLSERVER**\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib

This is for MSSQLSERVER instance, in case of different instance the registry path in bold gets replaced by name of that instance.

It needs restart of "SQLServer Service" of that instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid fiddling with the registry, the following should work.

From a `sqlps` prompt:

```
$smo = 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.'
$wmi = new-object ($smo + 'Wmi.ManagedComputer').
# Enable the TCP protocol on the default instance.
$uri = "ManagedComputer[@Name='" + (get-item env:\computername).Value + "']/ServerInstance[@Name='MSSQLSERVER']/ServerProtocol[@Name='Tcp']"
$Tcp = $wmi.GetSmoObject($uri)
$Tcp.IsEnabled = $true
$Tcp.Alter()
# Enable the named pipes protocol for the default instance.
$uri = "ManagedComputer[@Name='" + (get-item env:\computername).Value + "']/ServerInstance[@Name='MSSQLSERVER']/ServerProtocol[@Name='Np']"
$Np = $wmi.GetSmoObject($uri)
$Np.IsEnabled = $true
$Np.Alter()
```

And then restart SQL Server from good old `cmd`:

```
net stop MSSQLSERVER
net start MSSQLSERVER
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15